# Extend curve to touch box

Tags: r, plot, curve

I want to draw a function in R, for example

```
f <- function(x) log(x)
curve(f, c(0, 1))
```

This gives below:
[image]

How can I extend the curve to touch the box?

**Note:** I want to retain the four percent range extension of:

```
xaxs = "r"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try something like

```
curve(f, from=0, to=1.1, n=1001, ylim=c(-4,0), xlim=c(0,1))
```

to give a curve like

[image]

On the top right, the `to=1.1` extends the curve but the `xlim=c(0,1)` truncates it

On the bottom left the `n=1001` extends the curve downwards in the direction of x=0 and y=-infinity by adding more finite points but the `ylim=c(-4,0)` truncates it